Proof of transposed matrix related equation with Levi-Civita symbol
I would like to prove the following equation in relation to Levi-Civita symbol but I got stuck:
$$\left|{A^T}\right|=\left|{A}\right|, \tag{1}$$
where $A$ is a square matrix of size $3$.
I am also given the following equation to be used but I am not sure why this is the case:
$$|A|\epsilon_{lmn}=A_{li}A_{mj}A_{nk}\epsilon_{ijk}, \tag{2}$$
where $\epsilon$ is the means Levi-Civita symbol.
In an attempt to this, I tried expanding the right hand side of eq.$(2)$, but with three independent variables, I think it just results into $27$ expressions. Some of them may be the same result, such as numbers made from $(l,m,n)=(1,1,1),(2,2,2)$ etc, evaluating to zero.
How could I approach this problem?

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

What's your definition of determinant? This is fairly easy if you use a definition in terms of permutations.

This is a good video on this exact formula and a proof for it, I hope this can help you:
https://youtu.be/ydAVU7_utZA?si=V2PoJBVqSxZhkPQh
Edit: added :

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
